# Cloudinary: Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111]

Tags: python, python-3.x, cloudinary

I am trying to upload a file with Python -not Django- across Cloudinary API but I am getting "Failed to establish a new connection: [Errno 111]". I am executing this script in PythonAnywhere.

This is my code:

```
import cloudinary
from cloudinary.uploader import upload
from cloudinary.utils import cloudinary_url

cloudinary.config(
  cloud_name = "name",
  api_key = "API_KEY",
  api_secret = "API_SECURE",
  secure = True
)

upload("BookCoverTest.jpg")
```

And the error I am getting is this one:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/gcancino/notionBooks.py", line 148, in <module>
    queryWithFilter()
  File "/home/gcancino/notionBooks.py", line 71, in queryWithFilter
    getBookDataFromAPI(namee, pID)
  File "/home/gcancino/notionBooks.py", line 93, in getBookDataFromAPI
    upload("RitesofLucifer.jpg")
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/gcancino/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connection.py", line 174, in _new_conn
    conn = connection.create_connection(
  File "/home/gcancino/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 95, in create_connection
    raise err
  File "/home/gcancino/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/util/connection.py", line 85, in create_connection
    sock.connect(sa)
ConnectionRefusedError: [Errno 111] Connection refused

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/gcancino/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/cloudinary/uploader.py", line 534, in call_api
    response = _http.request("POST", api_url, param_list, headers, **kw)
  File "/home/gcancino/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 78, in request
    return self.request_encode_body(
  File "/home/gcancino/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/request.py", line 170, in request_encode_body
    return self.urlopen(method, url, **extra_kw)
  File "/home/gcancino/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/poolmanager.py", line 375, in urlopen
    response = conn.urlopen(method, u.request_uri, **kw)
  File "/home/gcancino/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 813, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
  File "/home/gcancino/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 813, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
  File "/home/gcancino/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 813, in urlopen
    return self.urlopen(
  File "/home/gcancino/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/connectionpool.py", line 785, in urlopen
    retries = retries.increment(
  File "/home/gcancino/.local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/urllib3/util/retry.py", line 592, in increment
    raise MaxRetryError(_pool, url, error or ResponseError(cause))
urllib3.exceptions.MaxRetryError: TCPKeepAliveHTTPSConnectionPool(host='api.cloudinary.com', port=443): Max retries exceeded with url: /v1_1/sampl
e/image/upload (Caused by NewConnectionError('<urllib3.connection.HTTPSConnection object at 0x7f7eb1283280>: Failed to establish a new connection:  [Errno 111] Connection refused'))
```

I have tried as well to configure this  but don't know what to put in proxy (execute that code in the bash console of PythonAnywhere)

```
export CLOUDINARY_URL=cloudinary://API_KEY:API_SECRET@DB?api_proxy=DONTKNOWWHATTOPUTHERE
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using a free account on PythonAnyhwere, you have a restricted internet access to whitelisted domains, see [whitelist](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/whitelist/).  If the endpoint you're trying connect to is a public API, you can request a whitelist addition by contacting PA stuff and providing links to official docuementation of the given API endpoint.

Comment: Hi and thanks for your response. They have ".cloudinary.com" indexed in the whitelist; so I don't know then why I am receiving this error. I don't think the code is the problem because when I run the code in my local computer, it works like a charm.

Comment: It could be a proxy issue then -- see [this PA forum post](https://www.pythonanywhere.com/forums/topic/29857/#id_post_95024)

Comment: did it with no results.